# How to create a password field for a user model in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I am completely new to Django. In my models.py, I want a User model to represent users that sign into the application.

I see how I could have fields like fname, lname, email, and username, (simply add "first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)", for example) but how would I have a password field so that users can be authenticated? Obviously it's a bad practice to store passwords in clear text.

Comment: Don't do this there are half a dozen tried and tested user authentication apps in django. django-allauth in particular stands out. Please use one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is built in django.contrib.auth user models which has following fields (username, firstname, lastname, password, email, groups, user_permissions, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, last_joined)

you can use this built in user model by creating user object and setting password for it.

```
 from django.contrib.auth.models import User
 user = User.objects.create(username="username", password = "password", email="email")
 user.save()
```

some fields in django user models are optional except username, password and email and by default it sets some fields like is_superuser='f' if you don't specify.

it will automatically store password in hash function and In future If you want to update any user's password you can get and update

```
 user = User.objects.get(username="username")
 user.set_password("password")
 user.save()
```

You can get an current online user instance by request.user

Answer (score 1):

Django's own AbstractBaseUser implementation:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
    password = models.CharField(_('password'), max_length=128)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(_('last login'), blank=True, null=True)
```

You store the password in a CharField, what you don't do is store it purely there, in fact calling the [set_password](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password) for the user like below,

```
user.set_password("Password")
```

Would hash the "Password" and save it into the `CharField`.

Edit

If you don't base your class on `AbstractBaseUser` and want to implement a `User` class from scratch, you need to hash all passwords and then save them. Inorder to hash the passwords, you can use the `make_password` function.

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
hashed_password = make_password(raw_password)
```

Comment: What if I don't want to use any built in classes? Can it still be done?

Comment: Yes it can, see the updated answer. You basically need to use the **make_password** method.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is functional - as in it will not throw an error, but I don't think it is correct.

What I encountered was `User.objects.create` does not hash password,  for that you should use `User.objects.create_user`